# Extracting 3 columns of data from a file and putting them in numerical order

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to write a program that opens a countryInfo.csv file and extracts the country name, capital city and population from each row, then writes a new file named country_simple_info.csv with country, capital and population in each row, with the rows sorted by population size, largest first. The file has columns with other information such as continent, languages, etc. but the code should ignore those. The following is my attempt at the code:

```
import csv
import operator
import sys

data = csv.reader(open('countryInfo.csv','r',encoding='utf-8'), delimiter='\t')
header = next(data)
sortedlist = sorted(data, key=operator.itemgetter(7), reverse = False)
with open("country_simple_info.csv", "w", encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    cvsWriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    cvsWriter.writerow(header)
    cvsWriter.writerows(sortedlist)
```

I don't understand how to make the code write only the 3 columns information and my attempt at making the population sorted did not work. Any help would be appreciated. The following is the file contents (Sorry about the bad formatting): EDIT:FORGOT TO MENTION I CANT USE PANDAS

```
iso alpha2  iso alpha3  iso numeric fips code   name    capital areaInSqKm  population  continent   languages   currency    geonameId
AD  AND 020 AN  Andorra Andorra la Vella    468.0   84000   EU  ca  EUR 3041565
AE  ARE 784 AE  United Arab Emirates    Abu Dhabi   82880.0 4975593 AS  ar-AE,fa,en,hi,ur   AED 290557
AF  AFG 004 AF  Afghanistan Kabul   647500.0    29121286    AS  fa-AF,ps,uz-AF,tk   AFN 1149361
AG  ATG 028 AC  Antigua and Barbuda St. John's  443.0   86754   NA  en-AG   XCD 3576396
AI  AIA 660 AV  Anguilla    The Valley  102.0   13254   NA  en-AI   XCD 3573511
AL  ALB 008 AL  Albania Tirana  28748.0 2986952 EU  sq,el   ALL 783754
AM  ARM 051 AM  Armenia Yerevan 29800.0 2968000 AS  hy  AMD 174982
AO  AGO 024 AO  Angola  Luanda  1246700.0   13068161    AF  pt-AO   AOA 3351879
AQ  ATA 010 AY  Antarctica      1.4E7   0   AN          6697173
AR  ARG 032 AR  Argentina   Buenos Aires    2766890.0   41343201    SA  es-AR,en,it,de,fr,gn    ARS 3865483
AS  ASM 016 AQ  American Samoa  Pago Pago   199.0   57881   OC  en-AS,sm,to USD 5880801
AT  AUT 040 AU  Austria Vienna  83858.0 8205000 EU  de-AT,hr,hu,sl  EUR 2782113
AU  AUS 036 AS  Australia   Canberra    7686850.0   21515754    OC  en-AU   AUD 2077456
AW  ABW 533 AA  Aruba   Oranjestad  193.0   71566   NA  nl-AW,pap,es,en AWG 3577279
AX  ALA 248     Åland   Mariehamn   1580.0  26711   EU  sv-AX   EUR 661882
AZ  AZE 031 AJ  Azerbaijan  Baku    86600.0 8303512 AS  az,ru,hy    AZN 587116
BA  BIH 070 BK  Bosnia and Herzegovina  Sarajevo    51129.0 4590000 EU  bs,hr-BA,sr-BA  BAM 3277605
BB  BRB 052 BB  Barbados    Bridgetown  431.0   285653  NA  en-BB   BBD 3374084
BD  BGD 050 BG  Bangladesh  Dhaka   144000.0    156118464   AS  bn-BD,en    BDT 1210997
BE  BEL 056 BE  Belgium Brussels    30510.0 10403000    EU  nl-BE,fr-BE,de-BE   EUR 2802361
BF  BFA 854 UV  Burkina Faso    Ouagadougou 274200.0    16241811    AF  fr-BF,mos   XOF 2361809
BG  BGR 100 BU  Bulgaria    Sofia   110910.0    7148785 EU  bg,tr-BG,rom    BGN 732800
BH  BHR 048 BA  Bahrain Manama  665.0   738004  AS  ar-BH,en,fa,ur  BHD 290291
BI  BDI 108 BY  Burundi Bujumbura   27830.0 9863117 AF  fr-BI,rn    BIF 433561
BJ  BEN 204 BN  Benin   Porto-Novo  112620.0    9056010 AF  fr-BJ   XOF 2395170
BL  BLM 652 TB  Saint Barthélemy    Gustavia    21.0    8450    NA  fr  EUR 3578476
BM  BMU 060 BD  Bermuda Hamilton    53.0    65365   NA  en-BM,pt    BMD 3573345
BN  BRN 096 BX  Brunei  Bandar Seri Begawan 5770.0  395027  AS  ms-BN,en-BN BND 1820814
BO  BOL 068 BL  Bolivia Sucre   1098580.0   9947418 SA  es-BO,qu,ay BOB 3923057
BQ  BES 535     Bonaire Kralendijk  328.0   18012   NA  nl,pap,en   USD 7626844
BR  BRA 076 BR  Brazil  Brasília    8511965.0   201103330   SA  pt-BR,es,en,fr  BRL 3469034
BS  BHS 044 BF  Bahamas Nassau  13940.0 301790  NA  en-BS   BSD 3572887
BT  BTN 064 BT  Bhutan  Thimphu 47000.0 699847  AS  dz  BTN 1252634
BV  BVT 074 BV  Bouvet Island       49.0    0   AN      NOK 3371123
BW  BWA 072 BC  Botswana    Gaborone    600370.0    2029307 AF  en-BW,tn-BW BWP 933860
BY  BLR 112 BO  Belarus Minsk   207600.0    9685000 EU  be,ru   BYR 630336
BZ  BLZ 084 BH  Belize  Belmopan    22966.0 314522  NA  en-BZ,es    BZD 3582678
CA  CAN 124 CA  Canada  Ottawa  9984670.0   33679000    NA  en-CA,fr-CA,iu  CAD 6251999
CC  CCK 166 CK  Cocos [Keeling] Islands West Island 14.0    628 AS  ms-CC,en    AUD 1547376
CD  COD 180 CG  Democratic Republic of the Congo    Kinshasa    2345410.0   70916439    AF  fr-CD,ln,ktu,kg,sw,lua  CDF 203312
CF  CAF 140 CT  Central African Republic    Bangui  622984.0    4844927 AF  fr-CF,sg,ln,kg  XAF 239880
CG  COG 178 CF  Republic of the Congo   Brazzaville 342000.0    3039126 AF  fr-CG,kg,ln-CG  XAF 2260494
CH  CHE 756 SZ  Switzerland Bern    41290.0 7581000 EU  de-CH,fr-CH,it-CH,rm    CHF 2658434
CI  CIV 384 IV  Ivory Coast Yamoussoukro    322460.0    21058798    AF  fr-CI   XOF 2287781
CK  COK 184 CW  Cook Islands    Avarua  240.0   21388   OC  en-CK,mi    NZD 1899402
CL  CHL 152 CI  Chile   Santiago    756950.0    16746491    SA  es-CL   CLP 3895114
CM  CMR 120 CM  Cameroon    Yaoundé 475440.0    19294149    AF  en-CM,fr-CM XAF 2233387
CN  CHN 156 CH  China   Beijing 9596960.0   1330044000  AS  zh-CN,yue,wuu,dta,ug,za CNY 1814991
CO  COL 170 CO  Colombia    Bogotá  1138910.0   47790000    SA  es-CO   COP 3686110
CR  CRI 188 CS  Costa Rica  San José    51100.0 4516220 NA  es-CR,en    CRC 3624060
CU  CUB 192 CU  Cuba    Havana  110860.0    11423000    NA  es-CU,pap   CUP 3562981
CV  CPV 132 CV  Cape Verde  Praia   4033.0  508659  AF  pt-CV   CVE 3374766
CW  CUW 531 UC  Curacao Willemstad  444.0   141766  NA  nl,pap  ANG 7626836
CX  CXR 162 KT  Christmas Island    Flying Fish Cove    135.0   1500    AS  en,zh,ms-CC AUD 2078138
CY  CYP 196 CY  Cyprus  Nicosia 9250.0  1102677 EU  el-CY,tr-CY,en  EUR 146669
CZ  CZE 203 EZ  Czechia Prague  78866.0 10476000    EU  cs,sk   CZK 3077311
DE  DEU 276 GM  Germany Berlin  357021.0    81802257    EU  de  EUR 2921044
DJ  DJI 262 DJ  Djibouti    Djibouti    23000.0 740528  AF  fr-DJ,ar,so-DJ,aa   DJF 223816
DK  DNK 208 DA  Denmark Copenhagen  43094.0 5484000 EU  da-DK,en,fo,de-DK   DKK 2623032
DM  DMA 212 DO  Dominica    Roseau  754.0   72813   NA  en-DM   XCD 3575830
DO  DOM 214 DR  Dominican Republic  Santo Domingo   48730.0 9823821 NA  es-DO   DOP 3508796
DZ  DZA 012 AG  Algeria Algiers 2381740.0   34586184    AF  ar-DZ   DZD 2589581
EC  ECU 218 EC  Ecuador Quito   283560.0    14790608    SA  es-EC   USD 3658394
EE  EST 233 EN  Estonia Tallinn 45226.0 1291170 EU  et,ru   EUR 453733
EG  EGY 818 EG  Egypt   Cairo   1001450.0   80471869    AF  ar-EG,en,fr EGP 357994
EH  ESH 732 WI  Western Sahara  Laâyoune / El Aaiún 266000.0    273008  AF  ar,mey  MAD 2461445
ER  ERI 232 ER  Eritrea Asmara  121320.0    5792984 AF  aa-ER,ar,tig,kun,ti-ER  ERN 338010
ES  ESP 724 SP  Spain   Madrid  504782.0    46505963    EU  es-ES,ca,gl,eu,oc   EUR 2510769
ET  ETH 231 ET  Ethiopia    Addis Ababa 1127127.0   88013491    AF  am,en-ET,om-ET,ti-ET,so-ET,sid  ETB 337996
FI  FIN 246 FI  Finland Helsinki    337030.0    5244000 EU  fi-FI,sv-FI,smn EUR 660013
FJ  FJI 242 FJ  Fiji    Suva    18270.0 875983  OC  en-FJ,fj    FJD 2205218
FK  FLK 238 FK  Falkland Islands    Stanley 12173.0 2638    SA  en-FK   FKP 3474414
FM  FSM 583 FM  Micronesia  Palikir 702.0   107708  OC  en-FM,chk,pon,yap,kos,uli,woe,nkr,kpg   USD 2081918
FO  FRO 234 FO  Faroe Islands   Tórshavn    1399.0  48228   EU  fo,da-FO    DKK 2622320
FR  FRA 250 FR  France  Paris   547030.0    64768389    EU  fr-FR,frp,br,co,ca,eu,oc    EUR 3017382
GA  GAB 266 GB  Gabon   Libreville  267667.0    1545255 AF  fr-GA   XAF 2400553
GB  GBR 826 UK  United Kingdom  London  244820.0    62348447    EU  en-GB,cy-GB,gd  GBP 2635167
GD  GRD 308 GJ  Grenada St. George's    344.0   107818  NA  en-GD   XCD 3580239
GE  GEO 268 GG  Georgia Tbilisi 69700.0 4630000 AS  ka,ru,hy,az GEL 614540
GF  GUF 254 FG  French Guiana   Cayenne 91000.0 195506  SA  fr-GF   EUR 3381670
GG  GGY 831 GK  Guernsey    St Peter Port   78.0    65228   EU  en,nrf  GBP 3042362
GH  GHA 288 GH  Ghana   Accra   239460.0    24339838    AF  en-GH,ak,ee,tw  GHS 2300660
GI  GIB 292 GI  Gibraltar   Gibraltar   6.5 27884   EU  en-GI,es,it,pt  GIP 2411586
GL  GRL 304 GL  Greenland   Nuuk    2166086.0   56375   NA  kl,da-GL,en DKK 3425505
GM  GMB 270 GA  Gambia  Bathurst    11300.0 1593256 AF  en-GM,mnk,wof,wo,ff GMD 2413451
GN  GIN 324 GV  Guinea  Conakry 245857.0    10324025    AF  fr-GN   GNF 2420477
GP  GLP 312 GP  Guadeloupe  Basse-Terre 1780.0  443000  NA  fr-GP   EUR 3579143
GQ  GNQ 226 EK  Equatorial Guinea   Malabo  28051.0 1014999 AF  es-GQ,fr    XAF 2309096
GR  GRC 300 GR  Greece  Athens  131940.0    11000000    EU  el-GR,en,fr EUR 390903
GS  SGS 239 SX  South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands    Grytviken   3903.0  30  AN  en  GBP 3474415
GT  GTM 320 GT  Guatemala   Guatemala City  108890.0    13550440    NA  es-GT   GTQ 3595528
GU  GUM 316 GQ  Guam    Hagåtña 549.0   159358  OC  en-GU,ch-GU USD 4043988
GW  GNB 624 PU  Guinea-Bissau   Bissau  36120.0 1565126 AF  pt-GW,pov   XOF 2372248
GY  GUY 328 GY  Guyana  Georgetown  214970.0    748486  SA  en-GY   GYD 3378535
HK  HKG 344 HK  Hong Kong   Hong Kong   1092.0  6898686 AS  zh-HK,yue,zh,en HKD 1819730
HM  HMD 334 HM  Heard Island and McDonald Islands       412.0   0   AN      AUD 1547314
HN  HND 340 HO  Honduras    Tegucigalpa 112090.0    7989415 NA  es-HN,cab,miq   HNL 3608932
HR  HRV 191 HR  Croatia Zagreb  56542.0 4284889 EU  hr-HR,sr    HRK 3202326
HT  HTI 332 HA  Haiti   Port-au-Prince  27750.0 9648924 NA  ht,fr-HT    HTG 3723988
HU  HUN 348 HU  Hungary Budapest    93030.0 9982000 EU  hu-HU   HUF 719819
ID  IDN 360 ID  Indonesia   Jakarta 1919440.0   242968342   AS  id,en,nl,jv IDR 1643084
IE  IRL 372 EI  Ireland Dublin  70280.0 4622917 EU  en-IE,ga-IE EUR 2963597
IL  ISR 376 IS  Israel      20770.0 7353985 AS  he,ar-IL,en-IL, ILS 294640
IM  IMN 833 IM  Isle of Man Douglas 572.0   75049   EU  en,gv   GBP 3042225
IN  IND 356 IN  India   New Delhi   3287590.0   1173108018  AS  en-IN,hi,bn,te,mr,ta,ur,gu,kn,ml,or,pa,as,bh,sat,ks,ne,sd,kok,doi,mni,sit,sa,fr,lus,inc INR 1269750
IO  IOT 086 IO  British Indian Ocean Territory      60.0    4000    AS  en-IO   USD 1282588
IQ  IRQ 368 IZ  Iraq    Baghdad 437072.0    29671605    AS  ar-IQ,ku,hy IQD 99237
IR  IRN 364 IR  Iran    Tehran  1648000.0   76923300    AS  fa-IR,ku    IRR 130758
IS  ISL 352 IC  Iceland Reykjavik   103000.0    308910  EU  is,en,de,da,sv,no   ISK 2629691
IT  ITA 380 IT  Italy   Rome    301230.0    60340328    EU  it-IT,de-IT,fr-IT,sc,ca,co,sl   EUR 3175395
JE  JEY 832 JE  Jersey  Saint Helier    116.0   90812   EU  en,fr,nrf   GBP 3042142
JM  JAM 388 JM  Jamaica Kingston    10991.0 2847232 NA  en-JM   JMD 3489940
JO  JOR 400 JO  Jordan  Amman   92300.0 6407085 AS  ar-JO,en    JOD 248816
JP  JPN 392 JA  Japan   Tokyo   377835.0    127288000   AS  ja  JPY 1861060
KE  KEN 404 KE  Kenya   Nairobi 582650.0    40046566    AF  en-KE,sw-KE KES 192950
KG  KGZ 417 KG  Kyrgyzstan  Bishkek 198500.0    5776500 AS  ky,uz,ru    KGS 1527747
KH  KHM 116 CB  Cambodia    Phnom Penh  181040.0    14453680    AS  km,fr,en    KHR 1831722
KI  KIR 296 KR  Kiribati    Tarawa  811.0   92533   OC  en-KI,gil   AUD 4030945
KM  COM 174 CN  Comoros Moroni  2170.0  773407  AF  ar,fr-KM    KMF 921929
KN  KNA 659 SC  Saint Kitts and Nevis   Basseterre  261.0   51134   NA  en-KN   XCD 3575174
KP  PRK 408 KN  North Korea Pyongyang   120540.0    22912177    AS  ko-KP   KPW 1873107
KR  KOR 410 KS  South Korea Seoul   98480.0 48422644    AS  ko-KR,en    KRW 1835841
KW  KWT 414 KU  Kuwait  Kuwait City 17820.0 2789132 AS  ar-KW,en    KWD 285570
KY  CYM 136 CJ  Cayman Islands  George Town 262.0   44270   NA  en-KY   KYD 3580718
KZ  KAZ 398 KZ  Kazakhstan  Astana  2717300.0   15340000    AS  kk,ru   KZT 1522867
LA  LAO 418 LA  Laos    Vientiane   236800.0    6368162 AS  lo,fr,en    LAK 1655842
LB  LBN 422 LE  Lebanon Beirut  10400.0 4125247 AS  ar-LB,fr-LB,en,hy   LBP 272103
LC  LCA 662 ST  Saint Lucia Castries    616.0   160922  NA  en-LC   XCD 3576468
LI  LIE 438 LS  Liechtenstein   Vaduz   160.0   35000   EU  de-LI   CHF 3042058
LK  LKA 144 CE  Sri Lanka   Colombo 65610.0 21513990    AS  si,ta,en    LKR 1227603
LR  LBR 430 LI  Liberia Monrovia    111370.0    3685076 AF  en-LR   LRD 2275384
LS  LSO 426 LT  Lesotho Maseru  30355.0 1919552 AF  en-LS,st,zu,xh  LSL 932692
LT  LTU 440 LH  Lithuania   Vilnius 65200.0 2944459 EU  lt,ru,pl    EUR 597427
LU  LUX 442 LU  Luxembourg  Luxembourg  2586.0  497538  EU  lb,de-LU,fr-LU  EUR 2960313
LV  LVA 428 LG  Latvia  Riga    64589.0 2217969 EU  lv,ru,lt    EUR 458258
LY  LBY 434 LY  Libya   Tripoli 1759540.0   6461454 AF  ar-LY,it,en LYD 2215636
MA  MAR 504 MO  Morocco Rabat   446550.0    33848242    AF  ar-MA,ber,fr    MAD 2542007
MC  MCO 492 MN  Monaco  Monaco  1.95    32965   EU  fr-MC,en,it EUR 2993457
MD  MDA 498 MD  Moldova Chişinău    33843.0 4324000 EU  ro,ru,gag,tr    MDL 617790
ME  MNE 499 MJ  Montenegro  Podgorica   14026.0 666730  EU  sr,hu,bs,sq,hr,rom  EUR 3194884
MF  MAF 663 RN  Saint Martin    Marigot 53.0    35925   NA  fr  EUR 3578421
MG  MDG 450 MA  Madagascar  Antananarivo    587040.0    21281844    AF  fr-MG,mg    MGA 1062947
MH  MHL 584 RM  Marshall Islands    Majuro  181.3   65859   OC  mh,en-MH    USD 2080185
MK  MKD 807 MK  Macedonia   Skopje  25333.0 2062294 EU  mk,sq,tr,rmm,sr MKD 718075
ML  MLI 466 ML  Mali    Bamako  1240000.0   13796354    AF  fr-ML,bm    XOF 2453866
MM  MMR 104 BM  Myanmar [Burma] Naypyitaw   678500.0    53414374    AS  my  MMK 1327865
MN  MNG 496 MG  Mongolia    Ulan Bator  1565000.0   3086918 AS  mn,ru   MNT 2029969
MO  MAC 446 MC  Macao   Macao   254.0   449198  AS  zh,zh-MO,pt MOP 1821275
MP  MNP 580 CQ  Northern Mariana Islands    Saipan  477.0   53883   OC  fil,tl,zh,ch-MP,en-MP   USD 4041468
MQ  MTQ 474 MB  Martinique  Fort-de-France  1100.0  432900  NA  fr-MQ   EUR 3570311
MR  MRT 478 MR  Mauritania  Nouakchott  1030700.0   3205060 AF  ar-MR,fuc,snk,fr,mey,wo MRO 2378080
MS  MSR 500 MH  Montserrat  Plymouth    102.0   9341    NA  en-MS   XCD 3578097
MT  MLT 470 MT  Malta   Valletta    316.0   403000  EU  mt,en-MT    EUR 2562770
MU  MUS 480 MP  Mauritius   Port Louis  2040.0  1294104 AF  en-MU,bho,fr    MUR 934292
MV  MDV 462 MV  Maldives    Malé    300.0   395650  AS  dv,en   MVR 1282028
MW  MWI 454 MI  Malawi  Lilongwe    118480.0    15447500    AF  ny,yao,tum,swk  MWK 927384
MX  MEX 484 MX  Mexico  Mexico City 1972550.0   112468855   NA  es-MX   MXN 3996063
MY  MYS 458 MY  Malaysia    Kuala Lumpur    329750.0    28274729    AS  ms-MY,en,zh,ta,te,ml,pa,th  MYR 1733045
MZ  MOZ 508 MZ  Mozambique  Maputo  801590.0    22061451    AF  pt-MZ,vmw   MZN 1036973
NA  NAM 516 WA  Namibia Windhoek    825418.0    2128471 AF  en-NA,af,de,hz,naq  NAD 3355338
NC  NCL 540 NC  New Caledonia   Noumea  19060.0 216494  OC  fr-NC   XPF 2139685
NE  NER 562 NG  Niger   Niamey  1267000.0   15878271    AF  fr-NE,ha,kr,dje XOF 2440476
NF  NFK 574 NF  Norfolk Island  Kingston    34.6    1828    OC  en-NF   AUD 2155115
NG  NGA 566 NI  Nigeria Abuja   923768.0    154000000   AF  en-NG,ha,yo,ig,ff   NGN 2328926
NI  NIC 558 NU  Nicaragua   Managua 129494.0    5995928 NA  es-NI,en    NIO 3617476
NL  NLD 528 NL  Netherlands Amsterdam   41526.0 16645000    EU  nl-NL,fy-NL EUR 2750405
NO  NOR 578 NO  Norway  Oslo    324220.0    5009150 EU  no,nb,nn,se,fi  NOK 3144096
NP  NPL 524 NP  Nepal   Kathmandu   140800.0    28951852    AS  ne,en   NPR 1282988
NR  NRU 520 NR  Nauru   Yaren   21.0    10065   OC  na,en-NR    AUD 2110425
NU  NIU 570 NE  Niue    Alofi   260.0   2166    OC  niu,en-NU   NZD 4036232
NZ  NZL 554 NZ  New Zealand Wellington  268680.0    4252277 OC  en-NZ,mi    NZD 2186224
OM  OMN 512 MU  Oman    Muscat  212460.0    2967717 AS  ar-OM,en,bal,ur OMR 286963
PA  PAN 591 PM  Panama  Panama City 78200.0 3410676 NA  es-PA,en    PAB 3703430
PE  PER 604 PE  Peru    Lima    1285220.0   29907003    SA  es-PE,qu,ay PEN 3932488
PF  PYF 258 FP  French Polynesia    Papeete 4167.0  270485  OC  fr-PF,ty    XPF 4030656
PG  PNG 598 PP  Papua New Guinea    Port Moresby    462840.0    6064515 OC  en-PG,ho,meu,tpi    PGK 2088628
PH  PHL 608 RP  Philippines Manila  300000.0    99900177    AS  tl,en-PH,fil,ceb,tgl,ilo,hil,war,pam,bik,bcl,pag,mrw,tsg,mdh,cbk,krj,sgd,msb,akl,ibg,yka,mta,abx    PHP 1694008
PK  PAK 586 PK  Pakistan    Islamabad   803940.0    184404791   AS  ur-PK,en-PK,pa,sd,ps,brh    PKR 1168579
PL  POL 616 PL  Poland  Warsaw  312685.0    38500000    EU  pl  PLN 798544
PM  SPM 666 SB  Saint Pierre and Miquelon   Saint-Pierre    242.0   7012    NA  fr-PM   EUR 3424932
PN  PCN 612 PC  Pitcairn Islands    Adamstown   47.0    46  OC  en-PN   NZD 4030699
PR  PRI 630 RQ  Puerto Rico San Juan    9104.0  3916632 NA  en-PR,es-PR USD 4566966
PS  PSE 275 WE  Palestine       5970.0  3800000 AS  ar-PS   ILS 6254930
PT  PRT 620 PO  Portugal    Lisbon  92391.0 10676000    EU  pt-PT,mwl   EUR 2264397
PW  PLW 585 PS  Palau   Melekeok    458.0   19907   OC  pau,sov,en-PW,tox,ja,fil,zh USD 1559582
PY  PRY 600 PA  Paraguay    Asunción    406750.0    6375830 SA  es-PY,gn    PYG 3437598
QA  QAT 634 QA  Qatar   Doha    11437.0 840926  AS  ar-QA,es    QAR 289688
RE  REU 638 RE  Réunion Saint-Denis 2517.0  776948  AF  fr-RE   EUR 935317
RO  ROU 642 RO  Romania Bucharest   237500.0    21959278    EU  ro,hu,rom   RON 798549
RS  SRB 688 RI  Serbia  Belgrade    88361.0 7344847 EU  sr,hu,bs,rom    RSD 6290252
RU  RUS 643 RS  Russia  Moscow  1.71E7  140702000   EU  ru,tt,xal,cau,ady,kv,ce,tyv,cv,udm,tut,mns,bua,myv,mdf,chm,ba,inh,tut,kbd,krc,ava,sah,nog   RUB 2017370
RW  RWA 646 RW  Rwanda  Kigali  26338.0 11055976    AF  rw,en-RW,fr-RW,sw   RWF 49518
SA  SAU 682 SA  Saudi Arabia    Riyadh  1960582.0   25731776    AS  ar-SA   SAR 102358
SB  SLB 090 BP  Solomon Islands Honiara 28450.0 559198  OC  en-SB,tpi   SBD 2103350
SC  SYC 690 SE  Seychelles  Victoria    455.0   88340   AF  en-SC,fr-SC SCR 241170
SD  SDN 729 SU  Sudan   Khartoum    1861484.0   35000000    AF  ar-SD,en,fia    SDG 366755
SE  SWE 752 SW  Sweden  Stockholm   449964.0    9828655 EU  sv-SE,se,sma,fi-SE  SEK 2661886
SG  SGP 702 SN  Singapore   Singapore   692.7   4701069 AS  cmn,en-SG,ms-SG,ta-SG,zh-SG SGD 1880251
SH  SHN 654 SH  Saint Helena    Jamestown   410.0   7460    AF  en-SH   SHP 3370751
SI  SVN 705 SI  Slovenia    Ljubljana   20273.0 2007000 EU  sl,sh   EUR 3190538
SJ  SJM 744 SV  Svalbard and Jan Mayen  Longyearbyen    62049.0 2550    EU  no,ru   NOK 607072
SK  SVK 703 LO  Slovakia    Bratislava  48845.0 5455000 EU  sk,hu   EUR 3057568
SL  SLE 694 SL  Sierra Leone    Freetown    71740.0 5245695 AF  en-SL,men,tem   SLL 2403846
SM  SMR 674 SM  San Marino  San Marino  61.2    31477   EU  it-SM   EUR 3168068
SN  SEN 686 SG  Senegal Dakar   196190.0    12323252    AF  fr-SN,wo,fuc,mnk    XOF 2245662
SO  SOM 706 SO  Somalia Mogadishu   637657.0    10112453    AF  so-SO,ar-SO,it,en-SO    SOS 51537
SR  SUR 740 NS  Suriname    Paramaribo  163270.0    492829  SA  nl-SR,en,srn,hns,jv SRD 3382998
SS  SSD 728 OD  South Sudan Juba    644329.0    8260490 AF  en  SSP 7909807
ST  STP 678 TP  São Tomé and Príncipe   São Tomé    1001.0  175808  AF  pt-ST   STD 2410758
SV  SLV 222 ES  El Salvador San Salvador    21040.0 6052064 NA  es-SV   USD 3585968
SX  SXM 534 NN  Sint Maarten    Philipsburg 21.0    37429   NA  nl,en   ANG 7609695
SY  SYR 760 SY  Syria   Damascus    185180.0    22198110    AS  ar-SY,ku,hy,arc,fr,en   SYP 163843
SZ  SWZ 748 WZ  Swaziland   Mbabane 17363.0 1354051 AF  en-SZ,ss-SZ SZL 934841
TC  TCA 796 TK  Turks and Caicos Islands    Cockburn Town   430.0   20556   NA  en-TC   USD 3576916
TD  TCD 148 CD  Chad    N'Djamena   1284000.0   10543464    AF  fr-TD,ar-TD,sre XAF 2434508
TF  ATF 260 FS  French Southern Territories Port-aux-Français   7829.0  140 AN  fr  EUR 1546748
TG  TGO 768 TO  Togo    Lomé    56785.0 6587239 AF  fr-TG,ee,hna,kbp,dag,ha XOF 2363686
TH  THA 764 TH  Thailand    Bangkok 514000.0    67089500    AS  th,en   THB 1605651
TJ  TJK 762 TI  Tajikistan  Dushanbe    143100.0    7487489 AS  tg,ru   TJS 1220409
TK  TKL 772 TL  Tokelau     10.0    1466    OC  tkl,en-TK   NZD 4031074
TL  TLS 626 TT  East Timor  Dili    15007.0 1154625 OC  tet,pt-TL,id,en USD 1966436
TM  TKM 795 TX  Turkmenistan    Ashgabat    488100.0    4940916 AS  tk,ru,uz    TMT 1218197
TN  TUN 788 TS  Tunisia Tunis   163610.0    10589025    AF  ar-TN,fr    TND 2464461
TO  TON 776 TN  Tonga   Nuku'alofa  748.0   122580  OC  to,en-TO    TOP 4032283
TR  TUR 792 TU  Turkey  Ankara  780580.0    77804122    AS  tr-TR,ku,diq,az,av  TRY 298795
TT  TTO 780 TD  Trinidad and Tobago Port of Spain   5128.0  1228691 NA  en-TT,hns,fr,es,zh  TTD 3573591
TV  TUV 798 TV  Tuvalu  Funafuti    26.0    10472   OC  tvl,en,sm,gil   AUD 2110297
TW  TWN 158 TW  Taiwan  Taipei  35980.0 22894384    AS  zh-TW,zh,nan,hak    TWD 1668284
TZ  TZA 834 TZ  Tanzania    Dodoma  945087.0    41892895    AF  sw-TZ,en,ar TZS 149590
UA  UKR 804 UP  Ukraine Kiev    603700.0    45415596    EU  uk,ru-UA,rom,pl,hu  UAH 690791
UG  UGA 800 UG  Uganda  Kampala 236040.0    33398682    AF  en-UG,lg,sw,ar  UGX 226074
UM  UMI 581     U.S. Minor Outlying Islands     0.0 0   OC  en-UM   USD 5854968
US  USA 840 US  United States   Washington  9629091.0   310232863   NA  en-US,es-US,haw,fr  USD 6252001
UY  URY 858 UY  Uruguay Montevideo  176220.0    3477000 SA  es-UY   UYU 3439705
UZ  UZB 860 UZ  Uzbekistan  Tashkent    447400.0    27865738    AS  uz,ru,tg    UZS 1512440
VA  VAT 336 VT  Vatican City    Vatican City    0.44    921 EU  la,it,fr    EUR 3164670
VC  VCT 670 VC  Saint Vincent and the Grenadines    Kingstown   389.0   104217  NA  en-VC,fr    XCD 3577815
VE  VEN 862 VE  Venezuela   Caracas 912050.0    27223228    SA  es-VE   VEF 3625428
VG  VGB 092 VI  British Virgin Islands  Road Town   153.0   21730   NA  en-VG   USD 3577718
VI  VIR 850 VQ  U.S. Virgin Islands Charlotte Amalie    352.0   108708  NA  en-VI   USD 4796775
VN  VNM 704 VM  Vietnam Hanoi   329560.0    89571130    AS  vi,en,fr,zh,km  VND 1562822
VU  VUT 548 NH  Vanuatu Port Vila   12200.0 221552  OC  bi,en-VU,fr-VU  VUV 2134431
WF  WLF 876 WF  Wallis and Futuna   Mata-Utu    274.0   16025   OC  wls,fud,fr-WF   XPF 4034749
WS  WSM 882 WS  Samoa   Apia    2944.0  192001  OC  sm,en-WS    WST 4034894
XK  XKX 0   KV  Kosovo  Pristina    10908.0 1800000 EU  sq,sr   EUR 831053
YE  YEM 887 YM  Yemen   Sanaa   527970.0    23495361    AS  ar-YE   YER 69543
YT  MYT 175 MF  Mayotte Mamoudzou   374.0   159042  AF  fr-YT   EUR 1024031
ZA  ZAF 710 SF  South Africa    Pretoria    1219912.0   49000000    AF  zu,xh,af,nso,en-ZA,tn,st,ts,ss,ve,nr    ZAR 953987
ZM  ZMB 894 ZA  Zambia  Lusaka  752614.0    13460305    AF  en-ZM,bem,loz,lun,lue,ny,toi    ZMW 895949
ZW  ZWE 716 ZI  Zimbabwe    Harare  390580.0    13061000    AF  en-ZW,sn,nr,nd  ZWL 878675
```

Edit: I can't use pandas

EDIT: I was looking through documentation and I think Dictreader and writer might be able to solve his problem

Comment: `pd.read_csv('countryInfo.csv')['name','capital','population'].sort_values('population',False).to_csv('here.csv')`

Comment: Doesn't that still utilize pandas?

Comment: yes.. you have to `import pandas as pd`

Comment: I am not allowed to use pandas in my solution. I edited my question with this info 30 min ago. Sorry about that.

Comment: you will then have to use nested lists to accomplish what you want

Comment: Would dictreader and writer work?

Answer (score 0):

The `csv` module doesn't have a way to extract just the columns, so my best bet would be to do something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51833192/extracting-3-columns-of-data-from-a-file-and-putting-them-in-numerical-order) using `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
saved_column = df.column_name #you can also use df['column_name']
```

which is so much easier.

Answer (score 0):

csv.reader does not play nice with the your csv format, please check tabs/spaces/commas.

For example, using your code with this csv works for me. (Note the changes in the commas, added hyphens)

```
iso-alpha2,iso-alpha3,iso-numeric,fips- 
code,name,capital,areaInSqKm,population,continent,languages,currency,geonameId
AI,AIA,660,AV,Anguilla,The Valley,102.0,13254,NA,en-AI,XCD,3573511
AL,ALB,008,AL,Albania,Tirana,28748.0,2986952,EU,sq-el,ALL,783754
AM,ARM,051,AM,Armenia,Yerevan,29800.0,2968000,AS,hy,AMD,174982
```